# Google Apps version for Moto E2

Tags: motorola-moto-e

What version of open gapps should I get if flashing android 7.1 Lineage Is on my Moto E2 Surnia XT1524

Answer (score 0):

A quick search tells me that Moto E2 runs on Snapdragon 410, which is a typical mid-end 64-bit SoC. However, I investigated its stock ROM and found it's a 32-bit one.

So you should download **OpenGApps ARM 7.1 pico** in order to get the bare minimum Google Play functionality. You may want to pick another package if you want to have more of Google, but remember to choose **ARM** from the first column and **7.1** from the second.

According to *Andy Yan*, if you attempt to flash a wrong OpenGApps package, it will refuse to install and tell you the right one you should pick.

Comment: E2 runs on a SD410. To OP: the package should error out and tell you which arch you should download even if you happen to download the wrong one.

Comment: @AndyYan I mistook E (2nd gen) for E2, or maybe I missed *Surnia*.